# group_by is not working when I use a formula

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

complete newbie here and struggling a bit.

I have a data set as below:

```
A tibble: 358 × 4
date         day             total            n 
01/01/2015  Thursday         162              52
02/01/2015  Friday           165              50
03/01/2015  Saturday         162              52
04/01/2015  Sunday           165              52
05/01/2015  Monday           162              48
06/01/2015  Tuesday          165              52
# … with 352 more rows
```

When I calculate the mean via formula like this:

```
   df %>%
 group_by(day) %>%
 summarise(avg = sum(total)/n)
```

It somehow does not summarise it and gives me 358 rows like this:

```
   day     avg
   <ord> <dbl>
1  Sun    116.
2  Sun    116.
3  Sun    116.
4  Sun    116.
5  Sun    116.
6  Sun    116.
# … with 352 more rows
```

Interestingly it summarises when I change "n" with a number divides sum(total) or when I use mean instead of my formula:

```
   df %>%
 group_by(day) %>%
 summarise(avg = mean(total))

   day     avg
   <ord> <dbl>
1  Sun    116.
2  Mon    135.
3  Tue    133.
4  Wed    134.
5  Thu    144.
6  Fri    165.
7  Sat    144.
```

Could somebody explain to me what the difference is between the two codes? It works when I use a number instead of "n".

PS: I am not sure if this is crucial to know but

1 - Dataset is order details for a year

2 - n is the count of days in that dataset

Comment: use `n()` instead of `n`

Comment: Just to add some more information. In your code `n` is not a single number but a vector. So in your code in each group you do not calculate a single value as a result, but the result is a vector again. `n()` on the other hand returns the number of rows in a group as a single number and therefore calculates the group mean correctly.